# How to create backup of the AWS managed hyperledger fabric blockchain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric

I have deployed the **AWS managed hyperledger fabric blockchain**. In the scenario when I would want to migrate to a self-managed hyperledger fabric blockchain or migrate to a different cloud service provider, how can I take the **backup** of the ledger data, certs, genesis block etc?

Answer (score 0):

State of ledger is stored in nodes in Amazon managed blockchain vpc. you can not take backup of ledger data.
However certs can be uploaded to S3 bucket for backup.
Genesis block can be part of your source control or CI/CD pipeline.